# ASP.NET - Dynamically register an HttpHandler in code (not in web.config)

Tags: c#, asp.net, httphandler, web-config, ihttphandler

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any way to add HttpHandler programatically in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888016/any-way-to-add-httphandler-programatically-in-net)

Is there a way I can dynamically register an `IHttpHandler` in C# code, instead of having to manually add it to the `system.web/httpHandlers` section in the web.config.

This may sound crazy, but I have good reason for doing this. I'm building a WidgetLibrary that a website owner can use just by dropping a .dll file into their bin directory, and want to support this with minimal configuration to the web.config.

Comment: This question is a duplicate and the answers appear to be inaccurate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't believe it's possible to modify the registered HttpHandlers once the AppDomain is running because the available handlers is read directly from the `web.config` file then cached in a private data structure.

If you knew upfront which extensions you wanted to allow, you could do is map these extensions to a single `HttpHandlerFactory` and then return a handler of your choice (by using dynamic assembly loading and reflection). For example:

```
<add path="*.ch1,*.ch2,*.ch3" verb="*" 
    type="MyHandlers.MyHandlerFactory, MyHandlers" />
```

Modifying the `web.config` at runtime would cause the AppDomain to restart.

Answer (score 17):

You can't modify the handlers but you can add a route to your hander programatically following these steps:

1. If its a WebForms app then ensure your webapp has the UrlRouting configuration in the web.config (yip breaks part of your initial requirement to have minimal changes to web.config) as explained by MS here: [Use Routing with Web Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668202%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)
2. Implement the IRouteHandler interface on your handler and return the hander as the result in its methods (see first example below)
3. Register your route (see second example below)

**Implement IRouteHandler**

```
public class myHandler : IHttpHandler, IRouteHandler
{
    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        // your processing here
    }

    public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

**Register Route:**

```
//from global.asax.cs
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RouteTable.Routes.Add(new Route
    (
        "myHander.axd",
        new myHandler()
    ));
}
```

There you have it. A hander registered though code. :)

Comment: This is the same method the StackExchange.MiniProfiler registers its route and handler for the UI element of it (you still need a handler entry for it though)

Comment: I have tried to implement this but the handler is not getting registered. Am I supposed to add some code to public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)?

Comment: @SSED `ProcessRequest` is what does the work for your handler. You have to add code there.

Answer (score 2):

When creating a control, I usually override the GetDesignTimeHtml function in my ControlDesigner class. From that function I check if the HttpHandler is registered, and if not, I register it. Here is the code I use to register the new HttpHandler:

```
    private void RegisterHttpHandler()
    {

        IWebApplication webApplication =
            (IWebApplication)this.GetService(typeof(IWebApplication));

        if (webApplication != null)
        {
            Configuration configuration = webApplication.OpenWebConfiguration(false);
            if (configuration != null)
            {
                HttpHandlersSection section =
                    (HttpHandlersSection)configuration.GetSection(
                    "system.web/httpHandlers");
                if (section == null)
                {
                    section = new HttpHandlersSection();
                    ConfigurationSectionGroup group =
                        configuration.GetSectionGroup("system.web");
                    if (group == null)
                    {
                        configuration.SectionGroups.Add("system.web",
                            new ConfigurationSectionGroup());
                    }
                    group.Sections.Add("httpHandlers", section);
                }
                section.Handlers.Add(Action);
                configuration.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Minimal);
            }
        }

    }
```

The Action property is a static HttpHandlerAction