# Dynamic adding HttpModules and HttpHandlers

Tags: asp.net-3.5

Is adding / removing HttpModules and HttpHandlers at runtime from a website a good idea ?
I am looking at ways to make my website as dynamic as possible without uploading changed content all over again. Something like config files.
Rule engines exist, but learning them seems like a pain. I might be wrong in my perspective. Please suggest possible ways to change logic in the code at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way is create a generic HTTPHandlerFactory which in turn returns the requested handlers.

Check out the [link](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=25339&seqNum=5) for more clarity

Answer (score 7):

ASP.NET 4 provides a PreApplicationStartMethod capability that can be used to add HttpModules programmatically.

I just did a blog post on that at http://www.nikhilk.net/Config-Free-HttpModule-Registration.aspx.

The basic idea is you create a derived HttpApplication that provides ability to add HttpModules dynamically at startup time, and it then initializes them into the pipeline whenever each HttpApplication instance is created within the app-domain.

Answer (score 5):

For .NET4 and above:

For dynamically installing a HttpHandler, you need to create a HttpModule wrapper to do that. See the answer to: [Any way to add HttpHandler programmatically in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888016/any-way-to-add-httphandler-programatically-in-net)

To dynamically add a http module:

> Install-Package Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure
>
> Install-Package WebActivator

```
[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(MyPreStartClass), "Start")]

namespace .....
{
    public static class MyPreStartClass
    {
        public static void Start()
        {
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(FooHttpModule));
        }
    }
}
```