# How to Modify web.config automatically when using Custom Server Control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, custom-server-controls

I am trying to create a Custom Server Control in C# using VS2008. I am using this custom control that actually requires me to modify the `web.config` file in order to add an `HttpHandler` when this control is added to the page of client.

My question is fairly simple:

What needs to be added to my custom control code so it registers the required `HttpHandler` information in the `web.config`? Some native controls already do this. For example, the `AJAX Toolkit` will modify the web.config. How can I do something similar with my control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an item in the toolbox of Visual Studio you can perform such an action when the developer drags and drops the control onto the web page. You need to decorate your control with `System.ComponentModel.DesignerAttribute` to refer it to a subclass (which you create) of  `System.Web.UI.Design.ControlDesigner`. In this class you can override `Initialize` and in there you can get hold of the config via `System.Web.UI.Design.IWebApplication` something like this:

```
var service = this.GetService(typeof(System.Web.UI.Design.IWebApplication)) as IWebApplication;
if (service != null)
{
    var configuration = service.OpenWebConfiguration(false);
    if (configuration != null)
    {
        var section = configuration.GetSection("system.web/httpHandlers") as HttpHandlersSection;
        if (section != null)
        {
            var httpHandlerAction = new HttpHandlerAction("MyAwesomeHandler.axd", typeof(MyAwesomeHandler).AssemblyQualifiedName, "GET,HEAD", false);
            section.Handlers.Add(httpHandlerAction);                
            configuration.Save();
        }
        else 
        {
            // no system.web/httpHandlers section found... deal with it
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        // no web config found... 
    }
}
else 
{
    // Couldn't get IWebApplication service
}
```

Comment: i hav writen below code but it didnt work.Please chek if anything wrong i m doing  if (service != null)
{
    var configuration = service.OpenWebConfiguration(false);
    if (configuration != null)
    {
        var section = configuration.GetSection("system.web/httpModules") as HttpHandlersSection;
        HttpModuleAction a = new HttpModuleAction("Tools","CC,Tools") ;section.add(a);

Comment: Once you've added the section you'll need to do a `configuration.Save()`

Comment: I have added the section configuration.Save(), But still it is not working ,Please help me.

Comment: @KrishnaYadav I've fleshed out the example a bit more, adding the HttpHandlerAction code. You might want add some code in the `else` blocks to make sure you're not ending up there.

Answer (score 0):

Review the [Any way to add HttpHandler programmatically in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888016/any-way-to-add-httphandler-programatically-in-net) thread, which descries how to accomplish a similar task at runtime. Hope this helps.