# Dynamically Load ASP.NET PAGE (Assembly DLL)

Tags: c#, asp.net, iframe, dll

I had found a similar topic about it, but it wasn't able to solve my problem,

[Dynamically load ASP.NET Page from DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19161948/dynamically-load-asp-net-page-from-dll)

I have my main project, like a default project, and need to load another project into this, example:

I have the "default.aspx" and need to load "website1.aspx" into this (IFrame, etc, I need suggestions about that as well), but "website1.aspx" is in a different project, not related to my main project (I'm trying to register the assembly to do that, but I can just access the methods, not the ASPX window)

It's something like my "default.aspx" is a master page and I need to load it inside other ASPX windows from different projects and DLLs.

I searched the web for some examples, but nothing so far.

I just need a hint to start searching about, any suggestions?

Comment: If you don't need to interact on server-side with it then use an iframe with the needed url, if you need to interact on the server side is a lot more complex as you will need to connect through http to the other page, modify the returned code as you need and then write it to an HTML literal or iframe.

Comment: The problem is: I don't have that external application hosted, it is inside my bin folder somewhere in my server already precompiled, I need to access this .dll file and display it inside